# Bootstrap multi select option on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap drop down for multiple select option, i want to get the current selection from the drop down option.

```
<select class="select_type selectpicker" data-width="30%" id="select_type" multiple="multiple" name="select_type" style="display: none;"><option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option></select>
```

i tried with the following, but didn't work

```
$("#select_type option").click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});

$("#select_type").delegate("click", "option", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try use jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function

```
$("#select_type").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/jdL7c9yp/2/

if you selected two options, output like `may,june`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#select_type option").click(function(){
    $("#select_type option:selected").each(function(e){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

It will alert each selected option, on option click event.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62wtm8zz/)